# Socket.io failing authorization does not retry to reconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, authorization, reconnect

I am using socket io with a simple token auth method (server side):

```
io.use(function(socket, next){

var handshake = socket.request;
if(token == handshake._query.token)
{
    console.log('Client authorized');
    next();
}
else
{
    console.log('Client not authorized');
    next(new Error('not_authorized'));
    socket.disconnect();
}
```

});

The problem is that if the client failed the first time authorization (wrong token), it does not retry to connect any more, even If I send a manual new connection it will not recconect until a total page refresh.
Cliend side:

```
var socket = io.connect(this.adress, {query: 'token=123456789', transports:['websocket', 'polling'] });
socket.on('error', function(err){
                console.log(err);
                if(err == 'not_authorized')
                {

                    console.log('gettin toke');//NOT ENTERING HERE
                }
                PS.connected = false;
            });
```

How can I retry reconnect with another parameter?

Workaround, set this variables againg to retry connecting:

```
                PS.socket.socket.connecting = false;
                PS.socket.socket.options.query = 'token='+tok;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation sample](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#authentication-differences) you should not use `socket.disconnect();`. Your client-side `error` event does not fire exactly because of this line.

**Edit:**

You may also try to set `forceNew` to `true` in connection options when reconnecting:

```
var socket = io.connect(this.adress, {
    query: 'token=123456789',
    transports:['websocket', 'polling'],
    forceNew: true
});
```

Comment: Even removing that does not solves. It seems that when the authorization fails connection cannot be retry any more.

Comment: I tested and it does not work, I found a workaround for version 0.9. In the edit